# simply-connected free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-simplicial complex

Tags: manifolds, covering-spaces, simplex

Is there any simply-connected free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-simplicial complex of dimension $2$ which its universal cover is $\mathbb{R}^2$?

For example, $\mathbb{S}^2$ has all the properties, except its universal cover is $\mathbb{S}^2$. Or, the tours with two hole have all the properties except it is not simply-connected!

Comment: What is the defining property of being a universal cover? If $X$ is simply connected, can you think of a simply connected space $\widetilde{X}$ and a surjective local homeomorphism $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$?

Comment: A covering space of a topological space $X$ is a topological space $C$ together with a continuous surjective map $P: C\to X$ such that for every $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that $p^{-1}(U)$  is a union of disjoint open sets in $C$, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ by $p$. A covering space is a universal covering space if it is simply connected.

Comment: So what is the universal covering space of any simply connected space $X$?

Comment: Thanks! Oh, I got it, it is an obvious question! So, obviously, my question has a negative answer!!

Comment: The answer is negative if your simplicial complexes are finite. If you allow infinite simplicial complexes, then $X=\Bbb{R}^2$ is an answer.

Comment: But, there is no free $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on $\mathbb{R}^2$!

Comment: More generally, if $X$ is an acyclic finite-dimensional simplicial complex, there cannot be a free action of a finite nontrivial group on $X$.